# Shift N Linked List Nodes To Front (C)

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, linked-list, nodes

Here's a problem I'm having some trouble with in C.
So, we have a function with two parameters:

1. struct list ** ptrptr
2. int K

K represents the number of Nodes that we have to shift from the end to the beginning of the list, like this:

[image]

I know how to shift one element, but I can't wrap my head around using tmps to solve with K nodes.

I would appreciate any suggestion.
Here's the code for one node.

```
void Shift(node **head){
   node *prev;
   node *curr = *head;
   while(curr != NULL && curr->next != NULL) {
      prev = curr;
      curr = curr->next;
   }
   prev->next = NULL;
   curr->next = *head;
   *head = curr;

}
```

Comment: For any value of `K`, you only have to keep track of 2 nodes -> the start and end nodes of the range.

Comment: You're almost done. Instead of finding the last node of the list you need to find the Kth last node of the list.

Comment: If you can do it for one, instead of trying all `K` at once, try doing one at a time `K` times.  Then think about trying all `K` at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can shift a complete chain of `K` nodes in a single "step".
Suppose the list consists of `N` elements, that `nmk` is the node at position `N-K`, and that `e` is the last node of the list. Then the code would be...

```
e->next = *head;
*head = nmk->next;
nmk->next = NULL;
```

The trick will now be to find node `nmk`, but I leave this up to you if you don't mind :-) 
And don't forget to check corner cases like empty lists, `N==K`, ....

Comment: If OP is doing this a lot with this list, a doubly-linked list would be simpler

Comment: @Mark Benningfield: Yes; and it would make the task "find node `nmk`" much easier :-)

Comment: Didn't mean to start a thread; I just thought you might want to mention it in your answer. Sorry, I should have been more clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Shift the last N nodes of a linked list to the front of
// the list, preserving node order within those N nodes.
//
// Returns -1 if there are not enough nodes, -2 for invalid N,
// 0 otherwise
int shift(list_t **head, int n) {
    list_t *t1, *t2;
    int i;

    if ((head == NULL) || (*head == NULL))
        return -1;

    if (n <= 0)
        return -2;

    // move initial pointer ahead n steps
    t1 = *head;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        t1 = t1->next;
        if (t1 == NULL) {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    t2 = *head;

    // t2 and t1 are now N nodes away from each other.
    // When t1 gets to the last node, t2 will point
    // to the node previous to the last N nodes.
    while (t1->next != NULL) {
        t1 = t1->next;
        t2 = t2->next;
    }

    // move the end nodes to the front of the list
    t1->next = *head;
    *head = t2->next;
    t2->next = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```